# Mouse/Touchpad not working in Mac OS X Lion Pre-Boot Authentication (PBA) with File Vault 2

Tags: mac, mouse, keyboard-layout, osx-lion, filevault

I set up File Vault 2 in Mac OS X Lion with Pre-Boot Authentication (PBA). In PBA-login my USB-keyboard is working, while using a wrong keyboard layout. I can neither use my magic touchpad nor an USB-mouse in PBA. Thus I can't change the keyboard layout located in the upper right corner. I tried unplugging all USB-devices except keyboard and mouse. Nothing seems to help and the mouse cursor isn't moving.

How can I get magic trackpad or USB-mouse to work in PBA login screen or manually set the used keyboard layout in PBA?

**Update**: Still no (USB-)mouse or bluetooth trackpad support in File Vault 2 Login Screen. Today I talked to Apple Support for over one hour with no result. Every idea is appreciated.

Comment: is this problem still unresolved?

Comment: I got a different USB-mouse working. Magic Trackpad is still not supported.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue and currently I found two workarounds:

**Workaround 1 - turn off/on the mouse**

- turn off the mouse (tiny on/off switch on the bottom of the mouse, put it in lower position)
- turn it on - small green led indicator should start to blink -> searching for bluetooth connection
- wait for a minute until the indicator turns steady (green light)
- check if mouse works
- if this doesn't work then repeat the process once more - i.e. turn off, wait until light becomes steady

My assumption is that there is some problem with bluetooth initialization in OSX in PBA mode  and this procedure resets something.

**Workaround 2 - reconfigure EFI login to display login as name/password**

Setup:

- system preferences / users&groups / login options / display login window as "name and password"
- delete some EFI login cached files like described here https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2013/06/19/enabling-filevault-2-pre-boot-login -screen-functions-from-the-command-line/ -

> in addition to running the defaults commands, you also need to remove
>   certain cache  filenames ending in .efires from
>   /System/Library/Caches/com.apple.corestorage/EFILoginLocalizations.
>   Clearing the filename.efires cache files forces the system to update
>   the FileVault 2 pre-boot login screen.

- i.e. do this (or move to some backup location) - `rm /System/Library/Caches/com.apple.corestorage/EFILoginLocalizations/*.efires`
- shutdown the computer
- start the computer -> you should get login window as "[username]/password" - where you don't need mouse but keyboard is enough

**Additional note:**

In console you may check login properties like this:

```
defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow
```

or you may change any of them - with

```
default write ...
```